# Analysis of Modular Matrix Exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I found this algorithm on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

```
function Matrix_ModExp(Matrix A, int b, int c)
    if (b == 0):
        return I  // The identity matrix
    if (b mod 2 == 1):
        return (A * Matrix_ModExp(A, b - 1, c)) mod c 
    Matrix D := Matrix_ModExp(A, b / 2, c)
    return (D * D) mod c
```

Can anyone explain to me the correctness proof and its time complexity? Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please. Currently it appears you are asking about the history of this algorithm, but it is unclear what you want to know about it.

Comment: @BDN, I thought someone found it already through research, can anyone mention it? If no, there must be a correctness proof of this algorithm, isn't there? Hopefully, someone can also mention the compact analysis of this algorithm ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know who first wrote this down, but: The algorithm uses simply the following properties of the power operation:

$$A^{0} = I$$
$$A^{n} = A\cdot A^{n-1}, \quad n \text{ odd}$$
$$A^{n} = A^{n/2} \cdot A^{n/2}, \quad n \text{ even} $$
The $\bmod c$ operation is defined element-wise.

Comment: I understand the $A^n$ when $n$ is odd, but how about $n$ is even?

Comment: If $n$ is even, then $\frac{n}{2}$ is an integer and therefore
$$A^{n} = A^{(\frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{2})} = A^{\frac{n}{2}} \cdot A^{\frac{n}{2}} $$

Comment: @ gammatester Ok I just realized how stupid I am. Thanks